# Error when sending 'user' observable from app component (async-pipe)

Tags: javascript, angular, object, asynchronous, async-pipe

Here is my App.component.ts file from where I am sending 'user' observable to the 'header' component as input.

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../core/auth/auth.service';
import { User } from '../../core/models/User';
import { Subscription, Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'trisha-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  user: Observable<User>;
  userSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.authService.user;
    this.userSubscription = this.authService.findme().subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.userSubscription) {
      this.userSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

---

Following is the App.component.html file

```
<trishapp-header [user]="user | async" (logoutEvent)="logout()"></trishapp-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---

Following is my header.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/core/models/User';

@Component({
  selector: 'trishapp-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() user: User;
  @Output() logoutEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  logout() {
    this.logoutEvent.emit();
  }
}
```

---

The problem is I am getting value in my header component properly, but maybe because of the following error my application is not working properly

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

Please help me I can't find anything wrong in my App.component.ts as the 'user' is already an observable

Comment: I am using Angular 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `this.user = this.authService.user;`, first you're stating the class property `user` of your component is the observable within your service, and you're right to use the `async` pipe to get the last emitted value;
- then, `this.user = user;`, you're stating the class property `user` of your component is the last emitted value of `authService.findMe()` Observable, so the setted value is already resolved and you cannot use the `async` pipe on it.

```ts
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.user = this.authService.user;
        this.userSubscription = this.authService.findme().subscribe(user => {
          this.user = user;
        });
      }
```

Comment: Yes it did solve that problem, but I will connect with you again regarding some issues in the demo project I am making :)